# Combinatorics for Autoregressive Functions - Reference

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

I am currently proving a theorem on the expressivity of functions which I have called "autoregressive". Take a finite set $S$ and two natural numbers $n,m\in\mathbb N$. For any function $a:S^n\to S$ we can define a function $\phi[a]:S^n\to S^m$ by applying $a$ $m$ times in an "autoregressive" way, by which I mean for $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)\in S^n$
\begin{equation}
\phi[a](x):= (a(x), a(x_2,\dots,x_n, a(x)), a(x_3,\dots,x_n, a(x), a(x_2,\dots,x_n, a(x))), \dots).
\end{equation}

**Question:** *I'm sure someone already thought of these functions. A reference would be greatly appreciated.*